# Error with WebView Kit, Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I've been having this error for quite a while now and I have no idea how to fix it.
"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
That's the exact error code that pops up. I know this might be a simple fix but I can't figure out how to fix this at all.

Here is my code for the webView Kit.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //webpage import

@IBOutlet weak var ParksView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

    ParksView.load(request)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

If someone could explain to me what I need to do to fix this problem, I would be forever grateful. Thank you!

Comment: There is literally like **millions** of questions about *Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*. Please do better research next time!

Answer (score 0):

It is failing on this line:

```
let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
ParksView.load(request)
```

Change it to this:

```
if let unwrappedURL = url {
    let request = URLRequest(url: unwrappedURL)
    ParksView.load(request)
}
```

Or:

```
guard url != nil else {return}

let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
ParksView.load(request)
```

This will make sure the `url` does not equal `nil`.

Comment: Adding to this: OP, your problem is actually that the url is nil. You should figure out why.

Comment: I am now getting a "Use of unresolved identifier 'request'" error on the ParksView.load(request) line.

Comment: Sorry I forgot - place that inside the `if` statement as well. This is because it did not go through the `if`, meaning that there is no variable named `request`

Comment: Looks like a `guard-let` statement would be more suitable.

Comment: Sorry, I am still a bit confused, what did you forget to place inside the if statement? Also which let statement do you think should be changed to guard-let?

Comment: I changed the question 9 minutes ago. Check that.

Comment: Neither of those worked.